# displaying button and label inline

Tags: html, css, inline

I want to display the button and label on the same line.But multiple buttons on different lines. How can I do that .Help will be appreciated.
Button and label should be side by side and next set of button and label on next line.
Where am I going wrong ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

.round-button 
{
    width:20px;


}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    overflow:hidden;

    background: #4679BD; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;

}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background:#30588e;
}
.round-button a {

    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;

    text-align:center;
    color:#e2eaf3;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}





    </style>
</head>
<body>


<br><span ><div class='round-button'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> <label style='display:inline;'>edit</label></span>

<br><span ><div class='round-button'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> <label style='display:inline;'>edit</label></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell` will give you expected output.

```
<span>
 <div class='round-button'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> 
 <label class="lblname" >edit</label>
</span>

<span >
  <div class='round-button'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> 
  <label class="lblname">edit</label>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.round-button 
{
 width:20px;
 display: table-cell;
}

.lblname{
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamvq16L/)**

**Note:** Try to avoid giving inline css.

Answer (score 3):

As there are some structural changes required in your html code so instead of tweaking little in your code you should consider restructuring it in proper manner. you can try following code.

```css
.button {
  background: #4679BD;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="button"></a><span>Button 1</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="button"></a><span>Button 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can't wrap a div(Block element) with a span(inline element) - **Invalid HTML**

And the problem is you aren't making button div `round-button`(Block element) inline or inline-block or float would also work.

As the `label is inline element` you don't need to display it to `inline`. Rather you need to change the button div to act as inline.

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class='round-button' style="display:inline-block">
      <div class='round-button-circle'></div>
   </div> 
   <label style='display:inline;'>edit</label>
</div> <!--/ END OF WRAP -->
```

I styled the `round-button`  div with **inline-block** because it would display inline as well maintaining block element css properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try floating:

```
.round-button {
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10564741)

Comment: @Mathias Why does it not provide an answer, if the CSS I suggested achieves the exact behavior that was asked for?

Answer (score 0):

just remove `<br>` in bitween both `<span>`
and add below to css

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Like i.e.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>

span {
    display:inline-block;
}
.new_line {
    width:780px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:50px;
    }

.new_line ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    padding:10px 22px ;
    }

.new_line ul li img {
    float:left;}
</style>
</head>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

.round-button 
{
    width:20px;


}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    overflow:hidden;

    background: #4679BD; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;

}
.round-button-circle:hover {
    background:#30588e;
}
.round-button a {

    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;

    text-align:center;
    color:#e2eaf3;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}





    </style>
</head>
<body>


<br><span ><div class='round-button'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> <label style='display:inline;'>edit</label></span>

<span ><div class='round-button'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> <label style='display:inline;'>edit</label></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this
hope helps
**Snippet**

```css
.round-button 
{
width:60px;


}
.round-button-circle {
 background: #4679bd none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 20px;

}
.round-button-circle:hover {
background:#30588e;
}
.round-button a {

width:100%;
padding-top:50%;
padding-bottom:50%;
line-height:1em;
margin-top:-0.5em;

text-align:center;
color:#e2eaf3;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:1.2em;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<span >
<div class='round-button'>
  <label style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">edit</label>
  <div class='round-button-circle'></div>
</div> 
</span>

<span >
  <div class='round-button'>
<label style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">edit</label>
<div class='round-button-circle'></div>
  </div> 
</span>
```